# Generating .proto file from existing Java objects or xsd

Tags: java, xsd, protocol-buffers

Does anyone know of any tools that will generate a .proto file? Either from an existing xsd or from existing Java objects?

I am using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) to make a web service call. The returned object has been auto generated from an xsd.

ok so I now want to pass this data using protocol buffers to another system. The object model is very complex and changes regularly - i.e. I get a new xsd every time the object model has changed. I would like to be able to auto generate a .proto file so that I can send data using google protocol buffers.

I have been looking everywhere but have come stuck.

I am happy to

i.) generate .proto file from the xsd
or
ii.) generate .proto file from the Java objects (which have been generated from the xsd)

I cannot find any way of doing this already short of writing something myself...
Your help much appreciated

Comment: I might be able to do it with xsd->c# (via xsd.exe)->.proto (via protobuf-net) - probably a bit brittle though, especially if the objects are complex....

Comment: mmm.. ok thanks ... that might be a workaround - I cant beleive that google dont provide a tool to do this as I am sure if they want people to take up this technology they would assume that taking on an exsting data model and converting it to a proto file would be quite a common use case - unless I have missed hte point of protocol buffers here...

Comment: I came across this project this morning. I have yet to try it, but it claims to support going straight from .xsd to .proto:
https://github.com/tranchis/xsd2thrift

Comment: So i had to recently do this for work, and i have open sourced the code. It quite simple, but it covers most of the common data structures that i use. You can get the code from [here](https://github.com/lloydsparkes/java-proto-generator)

Answer (score 3):

The Tranchis utility converts .XSD files to both .Proto and Thrift.

https://github.com/tranchis/xsd2thrift

It works quite well for converting basic schema types from XML Schema.

Comment: This one worked for me, there was a little warm-up time :) checked out project and ran locally jar. Commands on git are sort of outdated. One can check the jUnits to create commands and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`protostuff-runtime-proto`](https://github.com/webbynet/protostuff-runtime-proto) project from Github.
If you have protostuff RuntimeSchema, you can convert it to the .proto file by this code:

```
System.out.println(Generators.newProtoGenerator(schema).generate());
```

Comment: This project appears to never have had a release

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [proto-stuff](https://protostuff.github.io/docs/) will be helpful to you to some extent. I am not sure it generates the .proto file for you but **protostuff-runtime** automatically enables your existing pojos to ser/deser to various formats.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the thing is I still need to generate the proto file as I need to give this to the development team building the other side of the solution in c#... any other ideas? Thx