# Tool to convert Java classes to Proto definitions

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have an existing JAVA project that I'd like to convert the nested classes/objects to Protocol Buffers .proto definitions (not the other way around).

How do I convert it?

Comment: None of the java to proto def worked for me, some of the suggested options work only for the basic (simple) java class. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660203/generating-proto-file-from-existing-java-objects-or-xsd this answer. Here the xsd to proto works for complex xsd defs. There is no luck so far for java to proto.

Answer (score 2):

Reply to the previous one
Protobuf converters didn't work, this tool only convert java pojobean to proto message.

If you want to convert java class pojo code to .proto file, you could try protosuff here'
refer two git:
check：[protostuff]: https://github.com/protostuff